# How to open fxml file in netbeans?

Tags: javafx, netbeans

I am working with scene builder that I save as fxml file. When I open it on netbeans it generates the following error.

```
Executing C:\Users\Niw\Documents\NetBeansProjects\school_system\dist\run803183839\school_system.jar using platform C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
com/jfoenix/controls/JFXButton has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)``
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at school_system.School_system.start(School_system.java:29)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more

Exception running application school_system.School_system

Java Result: 1
```

What should I do?

Comment: Edit your question, so we can solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your application was compiled using JDK 9, but you are trying to run it using JRE 8:

- The relevant part of your stack trace which shows this is this message:

  > Caused by: java.lang.**UnsupportedClassVersionError**:
  >
  > com/jfoenix/controls/**JFXButton has been compiled by a more recent
  >   version of the Java Runtime** (class file version 53.0), 
  >   this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions
  >   up to 52.0
- The first line of your stack trace confirms that your are using JRE 1.8 which equates to class file version 52.0:

  > ...using platform C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre/bin/java
- However, your project has been compiled using JDK 9, which equates to class file version 53.0 as detailed in the error message for the `UnsupportedClassVersionError` shown above.

There are two possible ways to resolve your problem in NetBeans:

1. Use a more recent version of JRE to run your application, with a version >= JRE 9. To do that:

   - Select your project in the **Projects** pane, right click to open the context menu and select **Properties**.
   - Select **Libraries** from the list of **Categories**, then select a JDK from the **Java Platform** drop list which is >= JDK 9.
2. Use only JDK 8 (if, and only if, that is possible):

   - Select **Sources** from the list of **Categories**, then select a JDK 8 from the **Source/Binary Format** drop list.
   - Rebuild your application.

After taking one of those two approaches you should be able to run your application in NetBeans.